# Enforce Minimum Length by adding spaces

Tags: entities, rules, views

So currently I am using the maxlength module (https://drupal.org/project/maxlength) in order to enforce the fields maximum length and I have a view set up that is embedded to a php Rules action (Execute custom PHP code).

Basically if a field is smaller than the maxlength defined, I am looking for a way to output the value with spaces.

For example: Maxlength 5. Field Value: xxx. Output: "xxx  " (without quotes)

I can't seem to find the right module/php code to do this.

I think I have 3 directions I can go with this.

1. I have it save the spaces to the field based on the maxlength specified when saving the field. I don't like this option much since it actually adds spaces to the value in the database.
2. I somehow edit the view to display the spaces based on the maxlength of the field.
3. I edit the Rules views_embed_view php output.

Any help would be extremely helpful. Thank you.

Edit: I am using Drupal 7 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template file for your field you can use good old [PHP sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-4820):

```
$right = sprintf("[%10s]\n",    $s); // right-justification with spaces
$left  = sprintf("[%-10s]\n",   $s); // left-justification with spaces

$right === "    monkey";
$left  === "monkey    ";
```

In your case
    `<?php print $output; ?>`

should turn into:

```
 <?php printf("[%10s]", $output); /* if you want spaces before string */?>
```

Comment: So I could then create a new views-view-field tpl file for my field and alter the output. Awesome. I'm not too PHP savvy, so how would I go about using $right and 18 characters to edit the following output:

<?php print $output; ?>

Comment: @NWOM answer updated.

Comment: Ah thank you. I realized it as well. Would it possible to pull the maximum length variable from the field settings, rather than using a static value? This would make it dynamic for all fields. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @NWOM yes it would, but I can't tell how from the top of my head. Will try to come back later if I'll get an idea how.

Comment: @NWOM if you can bring value of earlier field there, you could use `printf("[%" . $length . "s]", $output);` to get your result. Any string can be built dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm sure that I'll be able to do this with the info you provided me!